# how to change export const in vue js

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vue-component

I have const:

```
export const globalUser = new Vue({
  created: function(){
    this.getActualUser();   
  },
  data: {
    ActualUser: {name:'',meta:'',tipo:''}
  },
  methods:{
    getActualUser: function(){
        var urlMeta='usuarioActual';
                axios.get(urlMeta).then(response=>{
                    this.ActualUser=response.data;
                });
    }   
  }
});
```

Now i'm importing that in a component of vue js

```
import {globalUser} from '../app.js'
```

Here is my data:

```
data:function(){
            return {
                usuarioActual:globalUser.ActualUser,
                anotherData:{}
            }
   }
```

This returns me:
"usuarioActual": {
    "name": "",
    "meta": "",
    "tipo": ""
  }, the data is empty.

What i want is the returns me data after the method getActualUser run:

> ActualUser: {name:'currentName',meta:'currentDat',tipo:'currentType'}

It works well:

```
axios.get(urlMeta).then(response=>{
                        this.ActualUser=response.data;
                    });
```

Comment: which vue-loader version you're using? it should support since ver 13.6.0 as mention in [this discusion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1234#issuecomment-380164460)

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a wrong way, maybe it will work.
I get a different solution:
Instead of using data in components, i'm using "props".
I don't need to import, just called the props in the blade template of laravel, there i can use @elements from laravel.
Props in component:

```
props:{
            usuario:String
        },
```

Now i'm using that:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<user-component usuario="{{ Auth::user()->name }}"></user-component>
@endsection
```

Works well, if you need more data u can add a function in the Model.
Now i can use that in my template of component

```
<template>
   <tr v-if="{{usuario}} =='Admin'">
```